# Facebook, Twitter and Gmail Integration in Android App

Tags: android, gmail, android-twitter, android-facebook

I have to share a link to facebook, twitter and gmail. I have implemented facebook integration using Facebook Sdk in my Android app, thus I am able to share my link to facebook. But if I am following the same procedure for twitter, facing lots of problem to integrate it in my app. Please help to solve this problem. Also I am not getting how to integrate same for gmail. Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Only for Gmail: one intent to start Gmail.

If you're using i.e. the Actionbar, you should think about the ShareAction Intent. Here is an example:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2012/02/share-with-intents.html

If the user has twitter/ facebook intalled on the device it is possible to open them and share them by using the share intent. Other Apps are also included. You ll face other probably other problems if the user is not using the offical facebook and twitter apps. I recommend you the shareintent.

Comment: Share intent is the way to go. Everything else is just a hax.

Comment: Yes, I have came across to share intent(facebook,twitter and gmail). But if twitter is not installed in the device, then I can face some problem. Also please let me know that, in gmail using share intent can I get the dialog as it look in compose mail. Also in the FROM field(compose mail), the user gmail id should come dynamically